# Can't register rteth0 for FEC Ethernet card on SabreLite iMX6Q

Tags: real-time, embedded-linux, network-protocols

I'm a new user on RTnet and try to make Rtnet work on Freescale Sabre Lite iMX6Q board. But I got an issue, RTnet can't use rt_fec.ko module driver to register rt_eth0 even though non real time driver is disable.

I'm using:
Linux kernel 3.0.43 download from Xenomai git://git.xenomai.org/ipipe-gch.git/?h=ipipe-3.0-imx6q
Xenomai 2.6 download from git.xenomai.org/xenomai-2.6.git/
RTnet 0.9.13 download from rtnet.org/download.html

Please see my kernel configuration and boot log in attached link.
Xenomai is loaded:

"*I-pipe: Domain Xenomai registered.

Xenomai: hal/arm started.
Xenomai: scheduling class idle registered.
Xenomai: scheduling class rt registered.
Xenomai: real-time nucleus v2.6.3 (Lies and Truths) loaded.
Xenomai: debug mode enabled.
Xenomai: starting native API services.
Xenomai: starting POSIX services.
Xenomai: starting RTDM services.*  "

And FEC ethernet driver (non real-time driver) is loaded when kernel is booting

*"FEC Ethernet Driver

fec_enet_mii_bus: probed  "*

Xenomai is built following install guideline for ARM platform from Xenomai:
http://xenomai.org/installing-xenomai-2-x/

RTnet is built by below command, because SABRE Lite use FEC ethernet card with Micrel KSZ9021 Gigabit chip so I put "--enable-fec" in configure command to build real-time driver for FEC ethernet card:

"./configure --host=armv7l-timesys-linux-gnueabi --with-rtext-config=/home/sonnguyen/rtnet-xenomai-rootfs/usr/xenomai/bin/xeno-config --with-linux=/home/sonnguyen/build/rtnet-xenomai-ipipe-imx6q --enable-rtcfg-dbg --enable-rtwlan --enable-net-routing --enable-router --enable-nomac --enable-rtcap --enable-proxy --enable-checks --enable-fec "

Then
"make DESTDIR=/home/sonnguyen/rtnet-xenomai-rootfs install"

I also changed RT_DRIVER from default value to "rt_fec" in rtnet.conf.
After kernel is booted, I ran "./rtnet start" and got this:

"RTnet: initialising real-time networking
RT FEC Ethernet Driver
./rtnet: line 385: can't create /sys/bus/pci/drivers/rt_fec/bind: nonexistent directory
initializing loopback...
RTnet: registered rtlo
RTcap: real-time capturing interface
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
RTcfg: init real-time configuration distribution protocol
RTmac: init realtime media access control
RTmac/TDMA: init time division multiple access control mechanism
ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device
ioctl (add): No such device
ioctl (add): No such device
ioctl (add): No such device
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
Waiting for all slaves...ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device   "

Then I tried:

"# lspci

lspci: /sys/bus/pci/devices: No such file or directory

## ls /sys/bus/

ac97          hid           mdio_bus      platform      sdio          spi
event_source  i2c           mmc           scsi          serio         usb "

No pci directory under /sys/bus/. Then I thought because the script can't find the ethernet physical bus, it can't register rteth0.
Then I looked into rtnet script and did some minor change. In the script it requires physical ethernet device ID (mentioned in REBIND_RT_NICS), so I tried to find out what it is and got this when make eth0 up with non real-time driver:

"eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver [Micrel KSZ9021 Gigabit PHY] (mii_bus:phy_addr=1:06, irq=-1)

PHY: 1:06 - Link is Up - 1000/Full "

I think 1:06 is my physical bus ID, then I change the code in rtnet from:

```
for dev in $REBIND_RT_NICS; do

    if [ -d /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver ]; then
        echo $dev > /sys/bus/pci/devices/$dev/driver/unbind
    fi
    echo $dev > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/$RT_DRIVER/bind
done
```

To

echo 1:06 > /sys/bus/mdio_bus/drivers/Micrel\ KSZ9021\ Gigabit\ PHY/unbind
echo 1:06 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/rt_fec/bind

And I tried again with "./rtnet start", this time I got this:

RTnet: initialising real-time networking

RT FEC Ethernet Driver
sh: write error: No such device
initializing loopback...
RTnet: registered rtlo
RTcap: real-time capturing interface
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
RTcfg: init real-time configuration distribution protocol
RTmac: init realtime media access control
RTmac/TDMA: init time division multiple access control mechanism
ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device
ioctl (add): No such device
ioctl (add): No such device
ioctl (add): No such device
ifconfig: SIOCGIFFLAGS: No such device
Waiting for all slaves...ioctl: No such device
ioctl: No such device

But it still said "No such device"
This is lsmod after I ran ./rtnet start

## lsmod

Module                  Size  Used by    Not tainted
tdma                   25691  0
rtmac                   9724  1 tdma
rtcfg                  58071  0
rtcap                   7151  0
rt_loopback             1279  2
rtpacket                6365  0
rtudp                  10738  0
rt_fec                 12742  0
rtipv4                 29987  2 rtcfg,rtudp
rtnet                  40746  9 tdma,rtmac,rtcfg,rtcap,rt_loopback,rtpacket,rtudp,rt_fec,rtipv4

## ./rtifconfig

rtlo      Medium: Local Loopback
          IP address: 127.0.0.1
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU: 1500

Only rtlo is registered.

I also tried with kernel linux without non real-time FEC driver (please refer in another config file in attached Skydrive link), but still the same issue happened.

Do you have any idea how to solve this issue? I did many search but still can not figure out how to fix it.

Because I can't attach the files to my post, so I put all of my configuration files in the link below:
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=162EDF85AEBD2EFE!717&authkey=!AJ1Fjd_XiohUwes&ithint=file%2czip

Best Regards,
Nguyen Hung Son